# Can Jackson serialize to JSON with customizable key name?

Tags: java, json, jackson

Is it possible to dynamically customize the key names in the JSON response at runtime, rather than creating individual POJO classes for domain level objects?

I am using Spring Boot 1.5.3 with Web Starter, so Jackson dependency is included. I am returning responses in JSON. Typically, I create individual POJO classes, with Jackson annotations if I need to customize key names. For example,

```
public class Movies {

    private List<String> movies;

    public Movies(List<String> movies) {
        this.movies = movies;
    }

    public List<String> getMovies() {
        return this.movies;
    }

    public void setMovies(List<String> movies) {
        this.movies = movies;
    }
}
```

When I am returning this from a `@RestController` with the following code:

```
@RestController
public class MoviesController {

    @Service
    private MovieService movieService;

    @RequestMapping("/movies/list")
    public ResponseEntity<Movies> getMovies() {
        return new ResponseEntity<Movies>(this.movieService.getMovies(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

I get back a JSON response when invoking this end-point:

```
{ "movies" : [ "Iron Man", "Spiderman", "The Avengers", "Captain America" ] }
```

I don't want to be creating the `Movies` POJO. Instead, I would like to have a generic-typed POJO:

```
public class GenericResponse {

   @JsonProperty("movies") // <- this needs to be dynamic
   private List<String> data;
   ...
}
```

...where I can somehow send any key name I want while instantiating `GenericResponse` as opposed to hard-coding the key name via a `@JsonProperty` annotation. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `Movies` and `GenericResponse` with `Map<String, List<String>>`, then do

```
map.put("movies", Arrays.asList("Iron Man", "Spiderman", "The Avengers", "Captain America"));
```

A `Map` is serialized to JSON as a JSON Object, with the map keys as field names, and map values and field values.

Answer (score 1):

What about doing this through Map ?

```
public class GenericResponse {
    @JsonValue
    private Map<String, List<String>> data;
  }
```

and you can use @JsonValue annotation to ignore the "data" field name !